# Pandas sum of variable number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this -

```
Time    1 A    2 A     3 A     4 A     5 A    6 A    100 A
    5    10     4       6       6       4      6      4
    3    7      19      2       7       7      9      18
    6    3      6       3       3       8      10     56
    2    5      9       1       1       9      12     13
```

The `Time` columns gives me the number of `A` columns that I need to sum up.So that the output looks like this -

```
 Time   1 A    2 A     3 A     4 A     5 A    6 A    100 A    Total
    5    10     4       6       6       4      6      4         30
    3    7      19      2       7       7      9      18        28
    6    3      6       3       3       8      10     56        33
    2    5      9       1       1       9      12     13        14
```

In other words, when the value in `Time` column is 3, it should sum up `1A, 2A and 3A`
when the value in `Time` column is 5, it should sum up `1A, 2A, 3A, 4A and 5A`

Note: There are other columns also in between the `As`. So I cant sum using simple indexing.

Highly appreciate any help in finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy - idea is compare array created by `np.arange` with length of columns with `Time` columns converted to index with broadcasting to 2d mask, get matched values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and last `sum`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Time')
m = np.arange(len(df1.columns)) < df1.index.values[:, None]
df['new'] = np.where(m, df1.values, 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   Time  1 A  2 A  3 A  4 A  5 A  6 A  100 A  new
0     5   10    4    6    6    4    6      4   30
1     3    7   19    2    7    7    9     18   28
2     6    3    6    3    3    8   10     56   33
3     2    5    9    1    1    9   12     13   14
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1)
      1 A  2 A  3 A  4 A  5 A  6 A  100 A
Time                                     
5      10    4    6    6    4    6      4
3       7   19    2    7    7    9     18
6       3    6    3    3    8   10     56
2       5    9    1    1    9   12     13

print (m) 
[[ True  True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True False False False False False]]

print (np.where(m, df1.values, 0))
[[10  4  6  6  4  0  0]
 [ 7 19  2  0  0  0  0]
 [ 3  6  3  3  8 10  0]
 [ 5  9  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: This code doesnt work as expected if I insert another row in between the As

Comment: So you want filter only values with `A` ? then use `df1 = df.set_index('Time').filter(regex=' A$')`

Comment: @eiram_mahera - there are values of `A` from `1` to `100` ?

Comment: yes. not fixed from 1 to 100, it can be from 1 to 60 or anything

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['total'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum([x[i+1] for i in range(x['Time'])]), axis=1)
```